# Allow return statement on void call

Tags: java, void

I am looking for a way in Java to allow a return statement to compile like so:

```
public void void1(){
  return;
}

public void void2(){
  return void1();   // compile error here
}
```

is there a way in Java to return a call on the same line if it's void? I end up having to do this of course:

```
   public void void2(){
      void1();   
      return;
   }
```

Comment: why you need return on void method?, and i will suggest to explain the use case as well

Comment: `return; void1();` although the readability is reduced.  However, in your specific case `void1();` would do the same thing (no need for `return`)

Comment: `void` wont return anything....

Comment: This is likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels just trying to reduce verbosity and put return on the same line. probably very slight perf penalty but less verbose. Mostly aesthetic/readability.

Comment: Trying to write code that fights against the known structure of the language will only *reduce* readability, not improve it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's probably true (but look at lambdas :)  .... `(() -> out.println("hmmmm"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way in Java to return a call on the same line if it's void

Yes, you can return on the same *line:* `void1(); return;`

But there's no way to return in the same *expression*: `return void1();`

Comment: yeah, maybe Java will introduce a super-duper `ultravoid` type someday, until then, here's to this!